# How to change to range format for ChartRangeFilter?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am writing to seek help, in how I can change the formatting for my ChartRangeFilter control, so it shows daily dates, instead of years:

Current output:
[image]

Is their particular controller properties i should be looking into:

```
   function drawVisualization(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
        if (dataValues.length < 1)
            return;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0], 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[1], 'Price');
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2], 'Type');
        data.addColumn('datetime', columnNames.split(',')[3], 'Date');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {


            var date = new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].Date.substr(6), 10));

            data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value, dataValues[i].Type, date]);
        }


        var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'dd MM yyyy' });
        var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'containerId': 'PieChartContainer',
            'options': {
                'width': 950,
                'height': 450,
                'legend': 'right',
                'hAxis': {
                    'format': "dd-MM-yyyy",
                    'hAxis.maxValue': 'viewWindow.max',
                    'maxValue': new Date(2014, 05, 30), 'minValue': new Date(2014, 04, 05),
                    'viewWindow': { 'max': new Date(2014, 05, 30) },
                },
                'title': chartTitle,
                'chartArea': { 'left': 100, 'top': 100, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 100 },
                'tooltip': { isHtml: true }
            },
            'view': {
                'columns': [{

                    type: 'string',
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        var date = dt.getValue(row, 3);
                        return dateFormatter.formatValue(date);
                    }
                }, 1, {
                    type: 'string',
                    role: 'tooltip',
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        return 'Name: ' + dt.getValue(row, 0) + ', Price: ' + +dt.getValue(row, 1) + ', Date: ' + +dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
                    }
                }]
            }
        });


        var myIdSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'control2',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 3,
                'ui': {
                    'chartView': { 'columns': [3, 1] }
                }
            }
        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample')).bind([myIdSlider], [line]).draw(data);
    }
```

Please advise. Many thanks.

Comment: Set the filter's `ui.chartOptions.hAxis.format` option.